# Google Script / appendRow() with local reference formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to append row with data + formula that is based on that data.

```
 sheet.appendRow([fullDate,'=LEFT(INDIRECT("R[0]C[-1]";FALSE);7)'])
```

In column A, i have full date in format `YYYY-MM-DD` and it want to make it short to `YYYY-MM` using local reference formula. When I type it by hand it works, but when I'm using appenRow, I've got formula parse error i gSheet. If I change anything in formula and accept it with 'return' it wokrs :/

Comment: Could you show more code please?

Comment: just tried this with an empty sheet and it works perfectly
`
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var fullDate = '2019-12-08';
  sheet.appendRow([fullDate,'=LEFT(INDIRECT("R[0]C[-1]";FALSE);7)'])
}
`

Comment: As @ДмитроБулах said, the statement is correct. Could you share the rest of your code and an example of the Sheet?

Comment: Might be due to the actual format of your variable fullDate. If it's a string, you could probably use the substring method in your script instead of using a formula. If it's a JS date, you may want to either convert it to a string first, or rather extract the year and month, and then concatenate them with a "-" in between. Some more code, as requested above, would indeed be useful.